# Laravel how to add relationship queries via model instance in controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working in a Laravel 9 project. I have a `Buyer` model which has a relationship called `tiers`, I need to load the count on here.

Right now, I'm doing it like:

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Company $company, Buyer $buyer)
{
    $this->authorize('view', Buyer::class);

    $buyer = Buyer::where('company_id', $company->id)
                    ->where('id', $buyer->id)
                    ->withCount('tiers')
                    ->first();

    if (!$buyer) {
        return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
            'message' => 'Buyer not found or invalid buyer ID.'
        ], 404);
    }

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($buyer);
}
```

There must be a better way since the buyer instance is already defined and working as the function argument.

Something like...

```php
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Company $company, Buyer $buyer)
{
    $this->authorize('view', Buyer::class);

    $buyer = $buyer->withCount('tiers');

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($buyer);
}
```

Why doesn't this work and what do I need to change to get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel has [deferred loading for counts](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#deferred-count-loading), so all you need to do is use `loadCount` instead of `withCount`, and there's no need to reassign the variable:

```
public function show(Company $company, Buyer $buyer)
{
    $this->authorize('view', Buyer::class);

    $buyer->loadCount('tiers');

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($buyer);
}
```